# Format datetime in model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, methods, model, formatting

I have a view which prints the date time as #{@event.starts_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")}. So everytime I print starts_at, I have to use strftime in the view. I need to find a way to add a method to my 'event' model, so that the date gets formatted automatically everytime I print event.starts_at or event.method_name(starts_at)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add method, but it will pollute model with view related logic. Best way is to create decorator for this purposes, if you are new with decorators then you can add it to model.

```
def starts_at_format format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"
   starts_at.strftime(format)
end
```

Now you can use `starts_at_format` and it will automatically format the date

`format` has default value so if ever later need to use other format just pass the argument.

You can this use as:

```
   starts_at_format
```

or

```
   starts_at_format("%m %d %b") # define format
```

Answer (score 6):

You can override the getter like follows:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  def starts_at
    attributes['starts_at'].strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
  end
end
```

Take into account that you have to use a string and not a symbol for the attributes hash.

Said this, this locks you if your app tries to get internationalized, as time formats are different depending on the locales

You could use the rails I18n for it:

**de.yml**

```
de:
  time:
    formats: 
      default: '%A, %d. %B %Y, %H:%M Uhr'
      long: '%A, %d. %B %Y, %H:%M Uhr'
      short: '%d. %B, %H:%M Uhr'
      very_short: '%d.%m.%Y, %H:%M Uhr'
```

With that you could use:

```
> I18n.localize Event.first.starts_at, format: :very_short
# => "26.11.2012, 10:35 Uhr"
```

The `localize` method is aliased to `I18n.l`

and it will use the right one (if defined)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. I though found one by adding the format to the initialisers and that sorted out the issue

Answer (score 0):

Consider using decorators with [draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper).

Simply create decorator

```
class EventDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  delegate_all

  def starts_at
    object.starts_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
  end
end
```

In controller do something like

`@event = Event.find(params[:id]).decorate`

can also use for multiple objects

`@events = Event.all.decorate`

and in view it will be automatically served the way you decorated it ;)